# How to figure the number of items donated by number of people on the team

Tags: calculus

We have multiple teams donating items.  We would like to calculate who wins based on the number of items donated per team member in their department.  For example:  You have one team donating 733 items with 19 team members and another donated 842 with 17 team members.  What is the best way to calculate the winner?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do this is to use the ratio of donated items to number of people.  So just take the number of items donated, 733, and the number of people so 19, and do

$733/19=38.6$

So in that department they donated on average 38.6 items per person.